# why the answer in this question is "(A)"?

Tags: grammar, questions

> **A pride of lions ____________ up to forty lions. Including one to three males, several females, and cubs.**

(A) can contain
(B) it contains
(C) contain
(D) containing

Why the answer is "A" NOT C?

I know that the object is a pride of lions so we need subject + verb so the answer must be it contains.

Comment: You've used a similar construction in the last sentence of your question. You say "the answer *must be*", not "the answer *it be". Match up the terms to identify the pattern: a pride of lions / the answer; can / must; contain / be.

Comment: So ... why didn't you use "it be"? The answer to that question might help explain why *can contain* works better than *it contains* in your quote.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple: because the subject is *a pride*, which demands a singular verb not a plural one. In more detail:

- A is unmarked for number, so can be used for either singular or plural.
- B duplicates the subject ungrammatically.
- C is a plural verb so you cannot use it with sentence’s singular subject
- D is not a finite verb.

The answer can therefore only be A.